# Cmake, size , diference after compile

Tags: cmake, size

I have a set of files. Compiled with gcc49 under FreeBSD. The default makefile, created by me. Well, that's not the problem.

Ok, I decided to compile with CMake.

-When compiling with default makefiles(gcc49) output target size is : 5 MB -When compiling with cmake(gcc49, same flags as in makefile default) output target is : 12 MB

My question is, why are so big differences in size.

I want the file to end, to be as small size, it was ok 5mb.

What should I do to make my 5mb file( with cmake)

THX all